# Use of asyncio's await in html body

Tags: python, flask, python-asyncio

I have a Python class which will check Postgres status; online or offline. It seems like I cannot use await keyword in html when using the `asyncio` library. See code below:

```
import asyncio
@dataclass
class Systemcheck:
    async def CheckDatabaseState(self) -> bool:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        return 0
```

**I have web route like that which I am massing by the class:**

```
@systemcheckviews.route('/systemcheck', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def systemcheck():
    return render_template("systemcheck.html", user=current_user, systemcheck=Systemcheck())
```

**At the end I have html which call the method:**

```
<p>
   {% if systemcheck.CheckDatabaseState() %}
      <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-success text-white">Online</div>
   {% else %}
      <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-danger text-white">Offline</div>
   {% endif %}
</p>
```

**My problem is when I put** `await` k**eyword here:**

```
{% if await systemcheck.CheckDatabaseState() %}
```

I am getting following error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxErrorjinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'systemcheck'
```

**I want to have async so my page can be shown to user immediately without waiting on method execution.**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you need to display the page before the check finished, you have to use some JS (AJAX) that will fill-in the result into the rendered page.

Comment: @VPfB any example?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

So, to me it looks like the code somewhat works with this:

```
   {% if systemcheck.CheckDatabaseState() %}
      <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-success text-white">Online</div>
      ...
```

and you only gets error when you insert 'await' into the code, like so:

```
{% if await systemcheck.CheckDatabaseState() %}
...
```

If thats the case, i would suggest to rewrite the `Class systemcheck` a bit. so your code only uses `{% if systemcheck.CheckDatabaseState() %}` without the `await`.

you have:

```
class Systemcheck:
    async def CheckDatabaseState(self) -> bool:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        return 0
```

i suggest this:

```
class Systemcheck:

    def checkDatabase():
        return asyncio.run(CheckDatabaseState)

    async def CheckDatabaseState(self) -> bool:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        return 0
```

and uses:

```
`{% if systemcheck.CheckDatabase() %}`
```

The syntax might not be 100% but i hope you get the idea and it helps.

Comment: It works but the page is still waiting to get final finish from the async - I would expect page loads when in background method is processing

Comment: Yeah the page would ofcourse have to wait in order to get the result from the async function! Does the page procceed when the result from the async function is returned?

Comment: Not really in C# when u put await the task can run in background and when result comes it shows up